# Is it possible to access a variable, using a string which holds that variables name in JAVA?

Tags: java, string, variables

In Java,
If I had a String already declared and it holds the name of a variable. Can I use that String to access that variable?
For Example

```
int sample=10;
String test = "sample";
```

Here,is it possible use the **string test** to access integer **variable sample**.
If yes, then how.

Comment: Read about reflection.

Comment: It's technically possible with reflection, but not really something you would do if there's an alternative. Why do you need to do that in the first place?

Comment: Reflection is limited to class fields, but in case of local variables you can try using `Map<String,Integer>` to store int values under some name.

Comment: Off topic and no hate on you OP, but I really hate it when people write Java as JAVA.

Answer (score 1):

## Reflection

One of the strongest aspects of Java is the robust reflection API provided by the standard libraries.

> Reflection allows you examine and modify the structures and behaviour of classes, methods, and attributes at runtime.

Reflection is, in my opinion, single handedly responsive for the robust Java ecosystem of platforms, frameworks, and JVM languages available today.

## Caution

While reflection is powerful and is definitely a part of Java widespread success I caution against using it in many circumstances.

For the most part reflection
 is used in software used by other software (frameworks, platforms, languages, etc).  Generally when I see someone ask about reflection (especially if they do not call it by name) they are thinking about the problem wrong.

*I would definitely like to hear your use case so we can possibly suggest a different way of looking at it.*

## Sample Code

Below is some psuedo code that illustrates one way to accomplish what you are trying to do. I call it psuedo code because I have not compiled it, and it could likely be optimized.

Before adding it to your project I would like to reiterate that you should post your specific problem so we can analyze it and possibly help you think about it differently.

```
final String ATTR = "test";
Class<?> clazz = Class.forName("your.fully.qualified.class.name");     
Field[] fields = clazz.getFields();

for ( Field field : fields ) {
    String name = field.getName();

    if ( name == ATTR ) {
       Object value = field.get(name);
   }
}
```